# Looking for a family of functions that satisfy $f\left(\frac1 x\right)+f(x)=1$ and maps $[0,\infty) → [0, 1)$ one-to-one

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, asymptotics

Title has it all.  The faster the better, it's for collision calculations in a game.  I like math but haven't had diffy, so I'm stumped.  Thanks!

If it helps, x is a ratio of two positive real numbers.

I was messing with arctan of the difference of the two positive real numbers, but it didn't seem to be working quite right.  I figure I need to work it more, since all my scribbles thus far seem to be point towards arctan as my solution.

Comment: You still gotta show your thoughts

Comment: $\dfrac{2}{\pi}\arctan x+\dfrac{2}{\pi}\arctan\dfrac1x=1$

Comment: The domain of $f$ cannot contain 0.

Comment: Sorry, I was on mobile.  Working on it now.

Comment: @MyGlasses: Dammit, it was arctan the whole time.  I'm an idiot.  If you want to put that in a question I'll mark it answered.

Comment: @kikjezrous It was an idea. The range of $\dfrac{2}{\pi}\arctan x$ is  $[0,1)$ for $x>0$.

Comment: Sure, but $\frac4 \pi \arctan x^n$ is perfect for me, and I can modify the steepness of the function's transition about $(1, 1)$ by changing $n$.  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hbubl2rlsf  Now, if there were just a comp sci person to help me make it fast...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:)** Let $$f(x)=\dfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}$$